# I can insert data to my database with Java but can't select and show it

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a database project with Java and MYSQL. I can connect database from Netbeans and i can insert data to it. But i have to reach my data and select sql statement does not work.

```
 public int TCSorgu(String sifre) {
        int deger=100;
        baglan("SELECT count(*) FROM PERSONEL WHERE P_TC=?;");
        addPS(1, sifre);
        r = calistir();
        try {
            r.next();
            deger = r.getInt("count(*)");
            System.out.println(deger);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAO_sorgu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        baglantiyiKes();
        if(deger==1)
            return 4;
        else
            return 2;
    }
```

this is my code where i try to "select" from database. I can reach data from Mysql so there is not problem with inserting. However the "count(*)" part gives 0 as result, when i run the same query in MYSQL it returns 1.

```
public void addPS(int index, String s){
    //System.out.println(index+s+"\n");
    if(ps != null){
        try {
            ps.setString(index, s);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}


  public ResultSet calistir(){

    try {
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return rs;
    //ps = null;
}

public synchronized void baglantiyiKes() {
    try {
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("baglantiyi kes hatasi : " + e);
    }
}
```

These are my helper methods. I can't find the problem.

Comment: Do not rely upon the column name having a wonky name `count(*)`. Instead rename it something along the line `SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM PERSONEL WHERE P_TC=?` and then use `r.getInt("cnt")`. And the semicolon at the end of the statement is not required.

Comment: what does `baglan()` do ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `deger = r.getInt("count(*)");` try `deger = r.getInt(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You might give the column expression a proper name.

```
baglan("SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM PERSONEL WHERE P_TC=?");
deger = r.getInt("cnt");
```

or simply use an index:

```
deger = r.getInt(1); // Columns counted from 1.
```

Also close the rs in general. And a terminating semicolon is not needed.